# Download a photo via RXJava2 and putting it on a special folder

Tags: android, image, file, download, rx-java2

How can I Download a photo using RXJava2 and put it into a folder in android internal memory so that downloaded photo be visible for file managers?

Comment: Just in the normal way. Nothing special. Put it in external storage.

Comment: This may help you.. **http://www.codexpedia.com/android/retrofit-2-and-rxjava-for-file-downloading-in-android/**